# Setting backgorund colors to canvas in Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have my code that displays 92 selectors and each selector has a canvas(where is set a background color depending on the value from selector), in Jquery I set backgorund colors to canvas for the each value form selector, my problem is that when I click other selector it sets the backround color to the first Canvas(form the first selector but not on his own Canvas), I have 92 selector and each have CANVAS, how can I manage to do this in JQUERY...

### Code

```
 <html>
   <head>
    <title>Tests</title>
    <style type="text/css">
     .table-container {
     display: inline-table;
     }
   table {
    width: 230px;
   }
  </style>
  <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">      
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('select').change(function() {
   var selected = $(this).find(':selected').val();
    if (selected == 'Forms') {
     $('#myCanvas').css('background','green');
    }
      if (selected == 'language Syntax') {
     $('#myCanvas').css('background','yellow');
     }
      if (selected == 'Fundamentals') {
     $('#myCanvas').css('background','red');
     }
      if (selected == 'Advanced Concepts') {
     $('#myCanvas').css('background','blue');
     }
      if (selected == 'New Concepts in PHP5') {
     $('#myCanvas').css('background','violet');
     } 
     if (selected == 'Operators and Functions') {
     $('#myCanvas').css('background','black');
     } 
     if (selected == 'Variables and Datatypes') {
     $('#myCanvas').css('background','brown');
     } 
     });
  });
   </script>
     </head>
    <body>
   <h3>Tests</h3>
  <div class="table-container">
 <table border="3">      
   <tr>
       <th>
 <?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","sergios.com");
 if (!$con)
 {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

 mysql_select_db("phptests", $con);


$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM question");

for($i=1;$i<93;++$i)
 { 
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Category"); 
 echo "Number:".$i."<br />";
 echo "<select>";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
  echo "<option>" .  $line['name'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>"; 
?>
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="20" height="20" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
   </canvas>
```

Comment: it's not clear what your question is.

Comment: I have 92 selector in a Column , each selector has a canvas , my problem is that when i click to a value from second or third selector from the column it not sets the background to his canvas but sets background color on the first Canvas from the first seletor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I observed, you are changing the same canvas element's color (id="myCanvas" => '#myCanvas'). Therefore, you need a way to uniquely associate each unique selector with each unique canvas.

There are more elegant ways of recoding what you have coded. Due to the constraint of time, here is a sample by utilizing html element class names.

```
// in php //////////
<?php
for($i=1;$i<93;++$i){ 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Category"); 
?>
    <br />
    Number: <?php echo $i; ?>
    <select class="<?php echo 'myCanvas_' . $i; ?>">
    <?php
    while($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $line['name']; ?>"><?php echo $line['name']; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    <canvas id="<?php echo 'myCanvas_' . $i; ?>" width="20" height="20" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;"></canvas>
<?php
}
?>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').change(function() {

        var toChangeCanvasId = '#' + $(this).attr('class');
        var selected = $(this).find(':selected').val();
        if (selected == 'Forms') {
            $(toChangeCanvasId).css('background','green');
        }
        if (selected == 'Fundamentals') {
            $(toChangeCanvasId).css('background','red');
        }

    });
});​
```

Comment: can u write the selectors in PHP not in javascript with all necesary modifications please!!!

Comment: selectors value are from Database , i can't connect mySql with javascript

Comment: let me change it to your database values